# How to specialize for member function type in template class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, template-specialization, specialization

I just tested the following codes, and I find out `std::is_function` doesn't accept member function types.(I'm not sure if this is true for other compilers, I'm using MVC++ Nov 2012 CTP)

```
   class Ac {
    public:
      float af(int) {}
    };

    int main() {
     std::cout <<  std::is_function<decltype(Ac::af)>::value << '\n'; //output is 0
    }
```

so I'm trying to implement it:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_member_function : std::false_type {};
template<typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
struct is_member_function<R (T::) (Args...)> : std::true_type {}; //this doesn't compile
```

For a member function pointer type, we can specialize for this signature: `R (T::*)(Args...)`
, but what is the corresponding syntax for a member function type?

Comment: What's wrong with [`std::is_member_function_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer)?

Comment: There is no member function data type in C++, there are only member function pointers.

Comment: `decltype(Ac::af)` is ill-formed -- under what compiler does the above code output `0`?  Ah, visual-studio-2012.  I see your problem! It is, as far as I know, illegal to talk about a non-static member function in quite that fashion without being in a context to call it and following it with the `(blah blah blah)` call, or prepending it with a `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears, [via this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer), that the following implmentation is used for is_member_function_pointer

```
template< class T >
struct is_member_function_pointer_helper : std::false_type {};

template< class T, class U> 
struct is_member_function_pointer_helper<T U::*> : std::is_function<T> {};

template< class T >
struct is_member_function_pointer : is_member_function_pointer_helper<
                                        typename std::remove_cv<T>::type
                                    > {};
```

So you can determine if something is a member pointer for something of type U using the T U::* and you can determine if T is a function type. I don't know of any syntax for a member function type, only a member function pointer type. I'd have to consult the standard to see if such a type can exist.

If it is the case that this does not exist you could implement a wrapper class which added the pointer for you like so.

```
template<class T>
struct is_member_function {
    static const bool value = std::is_member_function_pointer<T*>::value;
};
```

But when I try decltype(some_type::some_member) I get an error saying I can't just use some_type::some_member. a '&' is required

The following works for function member pointers

```
std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&foo::hello)>::value
```

It seems to me that you can only use member pointers and not just member types.

an alternate implementation of the above is_member_function_pointer_helper might look like

```
template<class... Args, class R, class U>
struct is_member_function_pointer_helper<R (U::*)(Args...)> : std::true_type {};
```